# SharePoint 2013 incoming email not stored in doclib

Tags: 2013, incoming-email

I have basic setup(automatic mode) of incoming email setting in SharePoint 2013 box. I have setup a SMTP server in front end web server.

I see my sent email appear in the drop folder for a while and then disappear, I guess it is picked up by the timer job. However I didn't see the email in the doc library.  The badmail folder also have nothing.

The ULS log have following entries:

> 12/22/2016 13:24:11.72    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0E98)
>     0x1808  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring
>     nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job
>   job-email-delivery). Parent No    6515b0de-9156-473d-bd3c-917505d3cf27
>   12/22/2016 13:24:11.72    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0E98)
>     0x1808  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data
>     xmnv    Medium      Name=Timer Job
>   job-email-delivery    9772c39d-dd34-407d-b071-93b18f5cfee3 12/22/2016
>   13:24:11.72   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0E98)
>     0x1808  SharePoint Foundation           E-Mail
>     6871    Information The Incoming E-Mail service has completed a batch. 
>   The elapsed time was 00:00:00.  The service processed 0 message(s) in
>   total.    9772c39d-dd34-407d-b071-93b18f5cfee3 12/22/2016 13:24:11.72
>     OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0E98)                       0x1808  SharePoint Foundation
>     Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (Timer Job job-email-delivery). Execution
>   Time=2.1928   9772c39d-dd34-407d-b071-93b18f5cfee3

Comment: If the mail appears in `Drop` and then disappears, you're indeed correct when thinking the SMTP server is well-configured + the incoming email job picked it up. So, the problem may be with the address you configured with your doc lib

Comment: Finally I solved the problem by switching the Incoming Email setting to Advance in CA, and specify the Drop folder. Don't know why the basic setting doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Incoming E-Mail Settings in your DocumentLibrary. There are some settings which control the behavior of how the mail is saved. You can configure to only save E-Mail attachments and not the mail itself ("Save original e-mail").

[image: Incoming E-Mail Settings of a DocumentLibrary]

Comment: I solved the problem by switching the Incoming Email setting to Advance in CA, and specify the Drop folder. Thanks.